# Function create_function() is deprecated in php7.2

Tags: laravel

Getting 
Function create_function() is deprecated Error in laravel 5.4 and php 7.2.
Not able to find solution.

please see below code

```
 public static function delimiterToCamelCase($string, $delimiter = '[\-\_]')
{
    // php doesn't garbage collect functions created by create_function()
    // so use a static variable to avoid adding a new function to memory
    // every time this function is called.
    static $callback = null;
    if ($callback === null) {
        $callback = create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[1]);');
    }
    return preg_replace_callback('/' . $delimiter . '(\w)/', $callback, $string);
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_function` has been deprecated as of php 7.2. Instead you can use [anonymous_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

```
if ($callback === null) {
     $callback = function ($matches) {
         return strtoupper($matches[1]);
     };
}
```

Comment: do i need to replace your code in delimiterToCamelCase function?

Comment: yes, but only If this code is not in the vendor directory